# Autoconfig and Autodiscover records added, Mail Apps still not discovering configuration

Tags: email, exchange, thunderbird, autodiscovery, autoconfiguration

I have setup `autodiscover` and `autoconfig` configuration over my linux server

[Auto Discover](http://autodiscover.brandsouls.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml)

[Auto Config](http://autoconfig.brandsouls.com/mail/config-v1.1.xml)

by following this [Tutorial](http://github.com/saurabh-sharma/ISPC-resources/tree/master/guides/autodiscover)

but my mailing apps are still not getting the configuration automatically. I have to configure it manually while adding account.

I am working on this for the very first time, so don't know much about it.
Need help over this.

Comment: `but my mailing apps are still not getting` --> Which apps that we talking here. Every app have their own discovery method

Comment: Mail app on Windows Phone, Android,

Mail app on Mac and Windows, Outlook, Thunderbird Mail

Comment: Hmm, not reproducible in my thunderbird. Here the [screenshoot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dW2MI.png). My squid also log connection to `TCP_MISS/200 2448 GET http://autoconfig.brandsouls.com/mail/config-v1.1.xml? z HIER_DIRECT/23.239.4.19 application/xml`

Comment: Can you test it on outlook? And currently its not working on my Android and Windows Phone. Is there any way of making it work over phones?

Comment: Sorry, I can't test it. Try to look into webserver log. If the your app make request to autoconfig/autodiscover URL, it should be logged.